# Doubt about the existence of a limit at infinity

Tags: limits, infinity

From what I know, limits only exist if both side limits exist and are equal:
$${\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L}$$ $$if$$ $${\lim_{x\to a^+}}f(x) = {\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x) = L}$$

But can this be applied to limits at infinity? In that case:
$${\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) = L}$$ $$if$$ $${\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)} = {\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x) = L}$$

Is this correct or ${\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)}$ should be taken as ${\lim_{x\to +\infty}} f(x)$ ?

Comment: Your definition for finite limits is wrong.  When people write things like $\lim_{x\to a_+}$ they mean "the limit as $x$ approaches $a$ from the right.  There is no condition at all on what happens near $-a$.

Comment: For $+a$ and $-a$, I guess you meant $a^+$ and $a^-$, which have very different meaning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit

Comment: Yes, I meant that :s

Comment: What book are you reading?

Comment: Calculus by Tom M. Apostol

Comment: Now that you have fixed the typo, can you answer your own question now? Note also that $\infty$ is *not* a real number. The notation $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ has a very specific meaning, either in terms of topology on ${\bf R}\cup\{\infty\}$ or the "$\epsilon$-M" language. What is it in Apostol's book?

Comment: You mean that because $\infty$ is not a real number that rule cannot be applied? In that case both limits are independent and ${\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)}$ should be evaluated only with positive $x$?

Comment: Infinity can only be approached from one side.

Comment: In Apostol's book it is clearly stated that limits at positive infinity are denoted like this ${\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)}$ So that confuses me when I look problems with the following notation ${\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)}$

Comment: You are confusing notation.  "positive infinity" is written $\infty$ or $+\infty$ and "negative infinty" is written $-\infty$.  The notation $a^+$ and $a^-$ means approaching via values larger than $a$ or via values less than $a$.  The notation $\infty^+$ or $-\infty^-$ would be meaningless as we can't approach infinity from values *more* than infty (or less than neg. infty).  And $\infty^-$ and $-\infty^+$ would be unnesc as we can *only* approach infty from those directions.

Comment: $+\infty$ and $\infty$ are considered the same.  Notice that $\lim_{x\to 5^-}$ means the "left-hand" limit.  That is as values of x that are less than postive 5 approach 5.  But $\lim_{x\to -5}$ means something entirely different.  That means the values of x as they approach *negative* 5.